# React Native Auth0 Google integration - error during the transport of processing this request

Tags: ios, react-native, google-signin, auth0

I've integrated `react-native-auth0` into React Native and configured Google provider. In the simulator everything works, however on the real device there is an issue, which doesn't occur each time. After Google 2FA I get the following error. Each like 3 try ends up with a successful login. The same thing happens on my device for other google accounts, also tested by my colleague with the same result on another device. At the moment tested only on iOS, not sure whether the same issue occurs on Android.

`There was an error during the transport or processing of this request. Error code = 7, Path = /v3/signin/_/AccountsSignInUi/data/batchexecute : Unknown HTTP error in underlying XHR (HTTP Status: 0) (XHR Error Code: 6) (XHR Error Message: ' [0]')`

Can't find anything helpful on the internet and Google documentation. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated, cause I'm stuck.